# How to fix Python Umlaut Dictionary Value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary containing (among others) this key value pair:

```
'Title': '\xc3\x96lfarben'
```

In German this translates to **Ölfarben**.

I have trouble to print this string to stout properly.
It is always printed as **Ãlfarben**

I already tried to use string.decode("utf-8"), string.encode("utf-8"), and many more combinations such as  unicode(string.decode("utf-8")) etc.

The problem is that I still have troubles to understand unicode, utf-8 etc.

Can anyone help?

**Update**

Here is some more information.
I am receiving a csv file report from the google adwords api (using the official python library to access the api). This data is presumably utf-8 encoded and stored to disk.

Then I use the dictreader method to read the csv from disk and convert it to a dict. Then I iterate of the data and use the print method. This is where the problem above occurs.

this is an entire line from the imported dict:

```
{'Destination URL': 'http://domain.com/file.html?adword={keyword}', 'Ad': 'Staffeleien', 'Campaign': '\xc3\x96 Farben', 'Ad group state': 'enabled', 'Ad state': 'enabled', 'Ad group': 'Farben', 'Campaign state': 'active'}
```

Comment: Can you give some more information on your terminal emulator? For me (Ubuntu 13.10, German setup) your encoded string prints fine as Ölfarben.

Comment: if you have trouble understanding unicode etc, read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html . What happens if you `print` the string?

Comment: just updated my post with some more information about the problem

Answer (score 3):

If you've added `u` to this string - dont do it, you should decode it at first. In unicode this string look like this: `u'\xd6lfarben'`:

```
>>> print u'\xc3\x96lfarben'
Ãlfarben
>>> print '\xc3\x96lfarben'.decode('utf-8')
Ölfarben
>>> '\xc3\x96lfarben'.decode('utf-8')
u'\xd6lfarben'
```

with `unicode` function:

```
>>> unicode('\xc3\x96lfarben', encoding='utf-8')
u'\xd6lfarben'
```